# How to run non-web Python Twisted script in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, twisted

Would have someone who understand Heroku and twisted ?

I have tested twisted code in my own computer

When the client calls the server

Server will return the message to the client

My purpose is to put the server on the heroku and let the client call it and return the message, do not have to use the web.

## Question

When I moved server code to Heroku

1. How to start the server.py?
2. How to set ip in client.py?

I use git clone heroku official code from [Getting Started on Heroku with Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#prepare-the-app)

After downloading the steps I do

1. Increase `twisted == 1.6.0` in requirements.txt
2. In the Procfile increase `worker: python server.py runserver 0.0.0.0: 5000` (server.py is twisted code)

3.`git push heroku master`

4. Go to the page Resources to start `worker: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000`

Have tried the connectTCP settings in client.py ("0.0.0.0", 5000, f), but did not respond

Press the open app will appear when the error message (but I did not use the website ....)

view log

```
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=bitserver.herokuapp.com request_id=778e3bd2-310d-4d8d-aa75-737a1d89efdc fwd="220.130.40.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

### The script info

```
server.py
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
import os
class Knock(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print 'Client:', data
        if data.startswith("Hey, Heroku!"):
            response = "Hi, please wait..."
            self.transport.write(response)
        else:
            response = "I don't know who you are!"
            self.transport.write(response)

class KnockFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Knock()

reactor.listenTCP(5000, KnockFactory())
reactor.run()
```

---

```
client.py
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class KnockClient(protocol.Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("Hey, Heroku!")

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        if data.startswith("Hi, please wait..."):
            print ("Heroku:",data)
            self.transport.loseConnection()
            reactor.stop()
    else:
        print ("Heroku:",data)
        self.transport.loseConnection()
        reactor.stop()

class KnockFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = KnockClient

def main():
    f = KnockFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP("0.0.0.0", 5000, f)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer on other forum

`Only web process types can receive connections, you'll need to setup any servers in the same way that you would with a web server, i.e., binging to 0.0.0.0:$PORT.`